# Hide default content textarea in Wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple thing to accomplish. But, it seems like I am not getting on top of it using Google search and stack-overflow etc.

**What I want is:**
In WordPress `'standard page'` admin panel, you always have the content text-area on top position. Since I added different input fields to define all of the pages content, there is no need of it anymore, so i would like to hide it for better usability.

**Question:**
Is there a way to hide the content text-area from the standard pages admin panel? And how to?

I know it is possible for custom post types! But, how do I get rid of it in the standard static page (admin panel)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_remove_post_type_support', 999 );
function my_remove_post_type_support() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}
```

Comment: Perfect! You nailed it ;) I have been pritty close but the 'editor' was unclear to me i tried content, the content etc... with little success. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Sid2009, may I know where to add this chunk of code in order to hide default wp's content editor?

Comment: @Mavichow - you add it into the functions.php file.